# How to run a javascript script before the other ones?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Do you know if it is possible to make sure that a JavaScript script site is ran first in a web page?

For the context, I'm trying to tag every `span` before another library (just like cufon) kicks in and messes with the original content. Since it's not possible to use `onLoad()` on spans, it's the only way I can see to do that on the client side.

Comment: Have you tried including the script just after where your `<span>`s are in your HTML, or anywhere _before_ your other scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order of precedence is determined by the order in which things load.

1. Head tag scripts (in the order they are listed)
2. Scripts & other event attributes in the order they appear in the code.
3. Body onLoad

I did have #2 & #3 mixed up - to clarify **the body onLoad event fires *after* the entire body (scripts included) loads**

Also, scripts altering `<span>` tags will have no effect if placed in the head tag (unless they are a function) since the script runs when it is loaded, and when the head loads, the body & span tags haven't loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Place `<script>` tag in page source after content that you need to modify, but before any other scripts. Scripts run in same order that their tags appear on page.